# How to show that the limit of the fractional parts of squareroots of powers of two does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}{(2^{\frac{n}{2}}-\lfloor 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor})$$ does not exist.
I tried to assume that there is a limit, and then show that it's not true, but got confused.

Comment: suggest you calculate the function for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,$ that should give you an idea.

Comment: I already tried and found that the difference is 2^0.5-1 or 2^0.5-2. I know that this function is always between one and zero, but dont know how to prove that it hasn't limit

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, the limit of your function isn't infinity. Are you sure you're asking the correct problem?

Comment: if you can show it oscillates between the two, then it can't hit a limit.  I.e. for every  value of n that gives you one value, you can find a bigger value of n that gives you another.  Also, you are probably referring to a limit of a SEQUENCE, not a function of x

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant sequence, and the limit is not infinity, for every value of n you get an answer between 0 and 1. How can I show that it happens always and not just in the begining?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What happens if $n$ is even? What happens if $n$ is odd? How can you use this?

Answer (score 0):

We know that the binary expansion of $$\tag1\sqrt 2=1_201101010000010011\ldots$$ is not terminating (not even eventually periodic), especially, there are infinitely many $m$ such that $2^m\sqrt 2$ (i.e. the expansion in $(1)$ shifted left by $m$ places) has a $1$ as first digit after the point. For such $m$, the number $2^m\sqrt 2-\lfloor 2^m\sqrt 2\rfloor$ is $\ge \frac12$, and this is the $(2m+1)$st term of the sequence. On the other hand, the terms at even positions are all just $0$. These two properties cannot hold together for a convergent sequence.